# Instantiate complex JS object properly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm fetching data over web service and I want to populate my object User with address object.

When trying to assign value to object this.user.address.residentialAddress I'm getting

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'residentialAddress' of undefined

Same error applies when trying to instantiate using constructor.
Simple console.log(this.user.address.residentialAddress.City); outputs value.

My guess is that I don't create object properly but I cannot see the solution?

```
private user: MyUser;
...
this.user = new MyUser();

this.user.address.residentialAddress = {
          City: data.address.residentialAddress.City,
          StreetAddress: data.address.residentialAddress.StreetAddress,
          Suburb: data.address.residentialAddress.Suburb,
          Province: data.address.residentialAddress.Province
};       


export class Address {    
    public StreetAddress: string;
    public Suburb: string;
    public City: string;
    public Province: string;

    constructor(street: string, suburb: string, city: string, province: string){
        this.StreetAddress = street;
        this.Suburb = suburb;
        this.City = city;
        this.Province = province;
    }
}

export class MyUser {    
    address: {
        residentialAddress: Address;
        postalAddress: Address;
    }
    ....

}
```

Comment: @Liam `this.user.address` is not an object typed with the class `Address`. It's an anonymous object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put address in the constructor:

```
export class MyUser {    
    public address: object;
    constructor(){
        this.address = {
            residentialAddress: Address;
            postalAddress: Address;
        }
    }

}
```

This would make `user.address` be defined after instantiation and the `Cannot set property 'residentialAddress' of undefined` should be gone.

Comment: ok, how would I access to user.address.postalAddress.City from a calling code in my example?

Comment: Wait, do you intend to reference these Objects rather in a static way? Because to access `City`, you would need first to instantiate `Address`:
`user.address.postalAddress = new Address(/* args here */);` and pass a city object into it's constrcutor. After that you can access City as described in your comment. To access them in a static way, you would have to redesign the whole structure here.

Answer (score 0):

```
private user: MyUser;
...
this.user = new MyUser();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Add this line `this.user.address = {}`
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
this.user.address = {}

this.user.address.residentialAddress = {
          City: data.address.residentialAddress.City,
          StreetAddress: data.address.residentialAddress.StreetAddress,
          Suburb: data.address.residentialAddress.Suburb,
          Province: data.address.residentialAddress.Province
};       


export class Address {    
    public StreetAddress: string;
    public Suburb: string;
    public City: string;
    public Province: string;

    constructor(street: string, suburb: string, city: string, province: string){
        this.StreetAddress = street;
        this.Suburb = suburb;
        this.City = city;
        this.Province = province;
    }
}

export class MyUser {    
    address: {
        residentialAddress: Address;
        postalAddress: Address;
    }
    ....

}
```